# Apparently weaker form of big O notation

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

If instead of saying there exists some $C \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \geq N$ we have $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ we say that there is some $C \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and
some subsequence $(f(n_{k}))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $(n_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ strictly increasing such that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $f(n_{k}) \leq Cg(n_{k})$, Is it a weaker condition? Or is it equivalent to $f(n) = O(g(n))$? Let it be or not, it reminds me of some theorems about sequences in mathematical analysis. Technique of change of variables made me ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get the terminology straight: when we have $A \Leftrightarrow B$, then we call $A$ and $B$ equivalent and its natural to say, that they are equally stronger. When we have $A \Rightarrow B$, but not $B \Rightarrow A$ ($B\nRightarrow A$), then we call $A$ more strong (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53708/precise-definition-of-weaker-and-stronger) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429568/meaning-of-strong-and-weak-formulas-in-propositional-logic)).

Outgoing from stated, your suggestion gives more weaker condition, because, $f\in O(g)$ in usual sense implies $f\in O(g)$ in new sense, but not reverse, as shows example:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}1, n \text{ is odd}\\
n, n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$
this function will be in "new" $O(1)$, but not in usual $O(1)$.

Comment: So is there some necessary and sufficient condition on a subsequence so that the original sequence is big O? We clearly can state something about odd and even subsequences but what I mean is just one subsequence.

Comment: It's interesting question: for example when sequence is monotone, then existence of just one convergent subsequence is enough to convergence of all sequence.